# Validar formulario reactivo en angular 9

Tags: angular

//Hola gente, tengo una gran duda sobre este tema de los formularios reactivos en angular, primero que nada les muestro mi *components.ts*

```
export class LobbyComponent implements OnInit {

  public form:FormGroup

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre: ['', Validators.required],
      apellido: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
      birth: ['', Validators.required],
      usuario: ['', Validators.required],
      password:['', Validators.required],
      repPassword: ['', Validators.required],
      sexo: ['', Validators.required]
    });

   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

   sexs = [
    {value: 'hombre', viewValue: 'Hombre'},
    {value: 'mujer', viewValue: 'Mujer'},
    {value: 'indefinido', viewValue: 'Prefiero no decirlo'}
  ];

  submitRegister(){
        console.log(this.form.valid)
  }
}
```

y a continuacion el *cmponent.html*

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitRegister()">
  <mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" name="nombre" formControlName="nombre" />
  </mat-form-field><mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Apellido</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" name="apellido" formControlName="apellido" >
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Usuario</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" name="usuario" formControlName="usuario">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="email" name="email" formControlName="email">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Fecha de nacimiento</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="birth">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Sexo</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="sexo">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let sex of sexs" [value]="sex.value" >
        {{sex.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Contraseña</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="password" autocomplete="new-password" formControlName="password"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="input-form-register">
    <mat-label>Confirme su contraseña</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="password" autocomplete="new-password" formControlName="repPassword"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button class="btn-block w-50" color="primary">Registrarme</button>
  <div>
    <small>Al registrarse usted estara aceptando nuestras <a href="">Condiciones y servicios</a></small>
  </div>
</form>
```

//Bien ahora si les voy a contar mis dudas, mi error y cual es el resultado que busco, primero y principal estoy tratando de validar dicho formulario, todo esta ok para mi, tengan en cuenta que no soy de desarrollar interfaces y logicas y esas cosas que se ejecutan en un browser, a la hora de validar el formulario, tengo entendido que si `this.form.valid` me devuelve `true` es por que todo esta ok, lo que pasa es que cuando lo muestro por consola siempre me devuelve `false`, y esta es mi duda, me tiene que devolver true? me tengo que guiar por ese valid a la hora de saber si esta todo ok o no? y por ultimo, 
en los campos del `formBuilder`, a la hora de agregar varias validaciones como es la manera de hacerlo?

les agradesco su atencion y su ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

Buen dia.
En tu funcion  submitRegister(), coloca  `console.log(this.form)`, para asi veas el status de tu formulario, veo que esta en PENDING, el tema es que en tu email,le has puesto 
`email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email]`, pero recuerda que en las validaciones el segundo 'argumento' son un arreglo si en caso hay mas de una validacion, en este caso :
`email:['',[Validators.required, Validators.email]]`.